# An inequality involving three consecutive primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample to the following claim :

> Let $p,q,r$ be three consecutive prime numbers such that $p\ge 11 $ and $p<q<r$ , then $\frac{1}{p^2}< \frac{1}{q^2} + \frac{1}{r^2}$ .

I have tested this claim up to $10^{10}$ .

For $p>5$ we get $\pi(2p)-\pi(p) \ge 2$  , a [result by Ramanujan](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanPrime.html) .
This means that $q<2p$ and $r<2p$ , so $\frac{1}{2p}<\frac{1}{q}$ and $\frac{1}{2p}<\frac{1}{r}$ which implies $\frac{1}{p} < \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}$ . If we square both sides of inequality we get $\frac{1}{p^2} < \frac{1}{q^2} + \frac{2}{qr} + \frac{1}{r^2}$ . Now , I don't know how to rule out term $\frac{2}{qr}$  .

Comment: Where did you find this claim? $(+1)$

Comment: @user477343 I made it  by myself...

Comment: Wow... brilliant :)

Comment: Let me tell you what I'm trying to explore this week, different versions/variations of the so-called Firoozbakht's conjecture. I try 
rewrite the inequality showed in Firoozbakht's conjecture for different arithmetic functions. My problem is that I can not to find one (from my experiments and knowledges) with a good mathematical content. Maybe a variation using Ramanujan primes instead of prime numbers has mathematical meaning. I say it if you want to explore it. Isn't required a response and good week.

Comment: @user477343 To be honest relation $1/p < 1/q+1/r$ was already known...:-)

Comment: Your result by Ramanujan doesn't prove the claim, for example 1/101^2 < 1/197^2 + 1/199^2 is false. You need two primes between p and 1.4142p.

Comment: @gnasher729 : The claim says three consecutive primes.

Comment: @gnasher729 $$\frac{1}{101^2}<\frac{1}{103^2}+\frac{1}{107^2}$$ as $(101,103,107)$ is a triplet of three **consecutive** primes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The inequality holds for all $p$ large enough. Let $a>1$ be such that $a^{-2}+a^{-4}=1$ and $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. By the Prime Number Theorem there is an $N$ such that $p_{n+1}<a\,p_n$ for all $n\ge N$.If $p\ge p_N$, then $q<a\,p$ and $r<a\,q<a^2\,p$ and
$$
\frac{1}{q^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}>\frac{1}{a^2\,p^2}+\frac{1}{a^4\,p^2}=\frac{1}{p^2}.
$$

Comment: And since $$a = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}} \approx 1.272 > \frac{6}{5}\,,$$ [we don't have to fear that $N$ must be large](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368798/understanding-a-famous-proof-by-jitsuro-nagura-need-help-understanding-one-step).

Answer (score 4):

***This is a comment as opposed to an answer***

---

All primes $p_{n+1} < 2p_n$. Let $p'$ be the prime before $p$, $q'$ be the prime before $q$, and $r'$ be the prime before $r$. Then, $$p+q+r< 2(p' + q' + r')$$ So $$\frac{1}{p^2} < \frac{1}{\big(2(p' + q' + r') - q - r\big)^2}$$ Also, $$\frac{1}{p^2} < \frac{1}{q^2} + \frac{2}{qr} + \frac{1}{r^2} = \left(\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)^2.$$ Consider $$\frac{1}{\big(2(p' + q' + r') - q - r\big)^2} < \left(\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)^2$$ then multiplying both sides by the denominator, subtracting $1$ from both sides, and then factoring, we get $$0 < \left(\left(\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)\left(2(p'+q'+r')-q-r\right) + 1\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)\left(2(p'+q'+r')-q-r\right) - 1\right)$$ Which is true since primes are always positive, the entire inequality is literally just a bunch of multiplication, and if $p' = 2$, $q' = 3$ and $r' = 5$ then this inequality holds.

Your conjecture would be thus true if $$\frac{1}{\big(2(p'+q'+r')-q-r\big)^2} < \frac{1}{q^2} + \frac{1}{r^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stronger form of the above inequality. The prime number theorem implies that for every $\epsilon$, there exists a prime $p_{\epsilon}$ such that for all $p > p_{\epsilon}$, we have $1 - \epsilon < \frac{p}{q}, \frac{q}{r} < 1$. Hence for all positive real $a$ and all primes greater than some $p_{\epsilon_a}$

$$
\frac{2 - \epsilon_a}{p^a} < \frac{1}{q^a} + \frac{1}{r^a} < \frac{2}{p^a}
$$